# Custom Action causes "No route matches" Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm am trying to have a form submit to a custom action.  The form won't even render, it just displays a error: 'No route matches'".

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :add_foo
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def add_foo
  puts "!!! in add_new_foo .. params = " + params + " !!!"
end
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= button_to 'download', add_foo_user_path(@user) %>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => add_foo_user_path(@user), :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could I suggest trying to output, directly in a view, `add_foo_user_path(@user)` to make sure that path method works, independent of the simple_form?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is defined correctly. The error is most likely raised because the @user instance is not present.